# paths inside jquery on multi level directory sites

Tags: php, jquery, html

OK!

jQuery is used in my navigation bar, and my nav bar is included in the header of each page with PHP.

The jQuery is used for replacing the background images of certain divs when they are clicked. However due to the multiple 'directory levels (eg website.com/'dir'/'dir')',  the root path of the image breaks.

I had this problem before with PHP which was fixed like this... (some context: Let's say that we are on page 'website.com/category/tag')

```
<?php $page_root_path = '../../'; ?> *I would add this at the top of the page to signify the directory depth and modify accordingly... *

<img src="<?php echo ($page_root_path); ?>img/nav/logo.png"
```

How would you transfer a PHP string variable to a jQuery string variable, and paste that variable into the root path contained in the css function below?

```
    $("#box").toggle();
    if ($('#box').is(":visible")) {
                $('.button').css({
                        "background-image": "<---PAGE_ROOT_PATH--->dir/dir/dir/img.png)"
    });
```

My knowledge of jQuery is partially lacking, so please explain to a newbie! :)

Comment: I would do it with css and use a path relative to the css sheet.

Comment: why not use `/` as the root instead of having to specify a path?

Comment: Have you tried `/img/nav/logo.png`? By using `/` it navigates to the root automatically.

Comment: I do use the css background-image property. The Jquery is for making it interactive. See how the link in this example sticks when it is clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/F3X6k/12/ Not currently aware of any css pseudo's for 'selected'.

Comment: thanks for the input guys. i use '../../' because css, assets and js have their own directories though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var globalUrl = '<?php print '/path/to/image/' ?>';
</script>
```

And use it in another script block;

```
$("#box").toggle();
if ($('#box').is(":visible")) {
            $('.button').css({
                    "background-image": globalUrl + "img.png)"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these solutions should work:

1. Paths are, by default, relative to the URL of the referring page. So if `img.png` is down in the directory hierarchy, it should be fine.
2. If you want instead the path to the image to be the same, no matter the level in the hierarchy, use

   a) absolute URLS with a leading slash `/imgs/img.png`

   b) a base url in the HTML header, with the `<base>` tag.
3. pass a directory in via your html file:

   ```
   <script>
   window._base_url = "<?php echo ($page_root_url); ?>";
   <script>
   ```

   and use that in your javascript

   ```
   $('.foo').css({'background-image': _base_url+"/foo/img.png"});
   ```
4. parse the current page url from `document.location.href` and do some surgery on that to find the right path.

These ideas are in increasing order of hassle.